# Profiling Google App Engine Project With Eclipse TPTP?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-tptp

How can I profile a google app engine project locally with the Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform?

I already installed the plugin, but when I choose to profile it, there is no option to profile it as a web application, only as a java application which doesn't work.

Update: It asks for a main class and I choose `com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain` which is the same Main class my run configuration uses, but then there is an error under the Monitor tab that says "IWAT0435E An error occured when connecting to the host."

UPDATE 2: I got rid of the error from update 1 by reinstalling eclipse. Now it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't seem like it's starting the server at all because no log messages show up on the console, and I can't connect to the web app on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use the TPTP plugin anymore as it is kind of dead (-> [project plan](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm)).

Take a look at the [CodePro Plugin](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html) contributed to the eclipse platform recently (by google).